# My scripts are running very slow in Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I recently started using Python with selenium and Pycharm as editor. When I run a small script just to fill in email fields and click next button. To perform those 3 steps it took nearly 25 secs. Not sure if these is any setting that I have to set to run the scripts faster. Below is the script I was running.

TestScenario_Package.py

```
import logging
import pytest

from PageUIObjectPackage.CreateAccountPages.EmailPage import CreateTxTAccountAddEmail
from PageUIObjectPackage.LoginPages.LoginPage import LoginToTxT
from UtilityPackage.CustomLoggerUtility import customLogger
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

TEST_INPUT_LIST = [("mgmwtest+22@gmail.com")]

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def module_header(request):
    pytest.log = customLogger(logging.DEBUG)
    pytest.log.info('Initializing web driver and test URL')
    pytest.baseURL = "https://txt.texas.gov/sign-in?welcome=tdlr"
    pytest.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    try:
        pytest.driver.maximize_window()
        pytest.log.info('Init Max window success')
    except Exception as e:
        pytest.log.error(e)
        pytest.log.error('Init webdriver failed')

    pytest.cal = LoginToTxT(pytest.driver)
    pytest.cae = CreateTxTAccountAddEmail(pytest.driver)

    def tear_down():
        pytest.log.info('In tear down module, completed running test')
        pytest.driver.quit()
        request.addfinalizer(tear_down)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("email", TEST_INPUT_LIST)
def test_create_account_toas(email):
    try:
        pytest.driver.get(pytest.baseURL)
        pytest.log.info('successfully opened the base URL')
    except:
        pytest.log.error('Exception when attempting to open the URL')
    if email:
        pytest.cal.clickCreateAccountButton()
        pytest.cae.EnterEmail(email, email)

    else:
        pytest.log.error('email id or password is not provided')
```

LoginPage.py

```
from UtilityPackage.CustomLoggerUtility import customLogger
from UtilityPackage.SeleniumDriverUtility import SeleniumDriver
import logging


class LoginToTxT(SeleniumDriver):

def __init__(self, driver):
    super().__init__(driver)
    self.driver = driver
    self.log = customLogger(logging.DEBUG)

#Locators in TxT login page
_CreateAccountButton = "//button[text()='Create Account']"           #xpath

def clickCreateAccountButton(self):
    self.elementClick(self._CreateAccountButton, locatorType="xpath")

def TakeScreenShot(self, resultMssage):
    self.screenShot(resultMssage)
```

Emailpage.py

```
import time

from UtilityPackage.CustomLoggerUtility import customLogger
from UtilityPackage.SeleniumDriverUtility import SeleniumDriver
import logging

class CreateTxTAccountAddEmail(SeleniumDriver):
def __init__(self, driver):
    super().__init__(driver)
    self.driver = driver
    self.log = customLogger(logging.DEBUG)

# Locators in TxT create account add email page
_EnterEmailField = "email"  # id
_ConfirmEmailField = "confirmEmail"  # id

def FillEmailField(self, email):
    if email:
        self.sendKeys(email, self._EnterEmailField, locatorType="id")
    else:
        self.log.error('email is not provided')

def FillConfirmEmailField(self, email):
    if email:
        self.sendKeys(email, self._ConfirmEmailField, locatorType="id")
    else:
        self.log.error('email is not provided')

def EnterEmail(self, email, confirmemail):
    if email and confirmemail:
        self.FillEmailField(email)
        self.FillConfirmEmailField(confirmemail)
        self.ClickNextButton(scrShtFileName="EmailPage_NextButtonClick")
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        self.log.error("Email is not provided")

def ClickNextButton(self, scrShtFileName):
    self.elementClick(self._NextButton, locatorType="xpath")
    self.TakeScreenShot(resultMssage=scrShtFileName)
```

Please find the attached video to see how slow it is performing to enter the details
[Samplerun](https://photos.app.goo.gl/MT3XxVt7uG7NgHxq7)

Console output

```
Testing started at 9:36 AM ...
"C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path "C:/Texas.gov/Automation Script/TestPackage/sampletest.py"
Launching pytest with arguments C:/Texas.gov/Automation Script/TestPackage/sampletest.py in C:\Users\Texas.gov\Automation Script\TestPackage

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\TestPackage
collecting ... collected 1 item

sampletest.py::test_create_account_toas[mgmwtest+22@gmail.com] 

============================= 1 passed in 51.28s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0
 
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 86.0.4240
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 86.0.4240
[WDM] - Driver [C:\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\86.0.4240.22\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
PASSED    [100%]  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 43, in <module>
    sys.exit(pytest.main(args, plugins_to_load + [Plugin]))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164, in main
    ret = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 306, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 257, in wrap_session
    session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 313, in _main
    config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 338, in pytest_runtestloop
    item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 110, in pytest_runtest_protocol
    runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 127, in runtestprotocol
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 216, in call_and_report
    call = call_runtest_hook(item, when, **kwds)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 255, in call_runtest_hook
    return CallInfo.from_call(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 310, in from_call
    result = func()  # type: Optional[TResult]
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 256, in <lambda>
    lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when, reraise=reraise
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 163, in pytest_runtest_call
    item.runtest()
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1627, in runtest
    self.ihook.pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem=self)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 184, in pytest_pyfunc_call
    result = testfunction(**testargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\TestPackage\sampletest.py", line 46, in test_create_account_toas
    pytest.cal.clickCreateAccountButton()
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\PageUIObjectPackage\LoginPages\LoginPage.py", line 57, in clickCreateAccountButton
    self.elementClick(self._CreateAccountButton, locatorType="xpath")
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 82, in elementClick
    element = self.getElement(locator, locatorType)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 71, in getElement
    self.waitForElement(locator, locatorType, timeout=2)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 149, in waitForElement
    print_stack()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 43, in <module>
    sys.exit(pytest.main(args, plugins_to_load + [Plugin]))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164, in main
    ret = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 306, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 257, in wrap_session
    session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 313, in _main
    config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 338, in pytest_runtestloop
    item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 110, in pytest_runtest_protocol
    runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 127, in runtestprotocol
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 216, in call_and_report
    call = call_runtest_hook(item, when, **kwds)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 255, in call_runtest_hook
    return CallInfo.from_call(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 310, in from_call
    result = func()  # type: Optional[TResult]
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 256, in <lambda>
    lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when, reraise=reraise
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 163, in pytest_runtest_call
    item.runtest()
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1627, in runtest
    self.ihook.pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem=self)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 184, in pytest_pyfunc_call
    result = testfunction(**testargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\TestPackage\sampletest.py", line 47, in test_create_account_toas
    pytest.cae.EnterEmail(email, email)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\PageUIObjectPackage\CreateAccountPages\EmailPage.py", line 41, in EnterEmail
    self.FillEmailField(email)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\PageUIObjectPackage\CreateAccountPages\EmailPage.py", line 24, in FillEmailField
    self.sendKeys(email, self._EnterEmailField, locatorType="id")
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 93, in sendKeys
    element = self.getElement(locator, locatorType)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 71, in getElement
    self.waitForElement(locator, locatorType, timeout=2)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 149, in waitForElement
    print_stack()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 43, in <module>
    sys.exit(pytest.main(args, plugins_to_load + [Plugin]))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164, in main
    ret = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 306, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 257, in wrap_session
    session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 313, in _main
    config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 338, in pytest_runtestloop
    item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 110, in pytest_runtest_protocol
    runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 127, in runtestprotocol
    reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 216, in call_and_report
    call = call_runtest_hook(item, when, **kwds)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 255, in call_runtest_hook
    return CallInfo.from_call(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 310, in from_call
    result = func()  # type: Optional[TResult]
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 256, in <lambda>
    lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when, reraise=reraise
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 163, in pytest_runtest_call
    item.runtest()
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1627, in runtest
    self.ihook.pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem=self)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 184, in pytest_pyfunc_call
    result = testfunction(**testargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\TestPackage\sampletest.py", line 47, in test_create_account_toas
    pytest.cae.EnterEmail(email, email)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\PageUIObjectPackage\CreateAccountPages\EmailPage.py", line 42, in EnterEmail
    self.FillConfirmEmailField(confirmemail)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\PageUIObjectPackage\CreateAccountPages\EmailPage.py", line 32, in FillConfirmEmailField
    self.sendKeys(email, self._ConfirmEmailField, locatorType="id")
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 93, in sendKeys
    element = self.getElement(locator, locatorType)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 71, in getElement
    self.waitForElement(locator, locatorType, timeout=2)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\UtilityPackage\SeleniumDriverUtility.py", line 149, in waitForElement
    print_stack()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 43, in <module>
    sys.exit(pytest.main(args, plugins_to_load + [Plugin]))
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164, in main
    ret = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 306, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 257, in wrap_session
    session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 313, in _main
    config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "C:\Texas.gov\Automation Script\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the script?  All I see is a bunch of function definitions, but there is no top-level main code that would actually _call_ those functions.

Comment: This is quite broad/vague. In any case, PyCharm is unlikely to be the issue here.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon , have updated my question with the complete package. Please let me know if there is anything else you need.

Answer (score 1):

I found whats the issue for my slowness. In the project, it is using the Seleniumdriverutility.py package and in the method, WaitForElement is not returning the element and so it's waiting for the complete timeout. Do you have any idea why it's not returning the element?

The below script from this Git [Selenium driver for Python](https://github.com/venkywarriors/selenium_with_python/blob/b9793f83272d126e14ede23ce2ad60e658615a50/Python_basics/AutomationFramework_Part_1/167%206-selenium-driver.py#L34)

```
def waitForElement(self, locator, locatorType="id",
                           timeout=10, pollFrequency=0.5):
    element = None
    try:
        byType = self.getByType(locatorType)
        print("Waiting for maximum :: " + str(timeout) +
              " :: seconds for element to be clickable")
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, poll_frequency=1,
                             ignored_exceptions=[NoSuchElementException,
                                                 ElementNotVisibleException,
                                                 ElementNotSelectableException])
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((byType,
                                                         "stopFilter_stops-0")))
        print("Element appeared on the web page")
    except:
        print("Element not appeared on the web page")
        print_stack()
    return element
```